# How do i import a xml tag with JavaScript to display an image in html

Tags: javascript, html, xml, image

I am very very new to XML.  I need to use JavaScript to import an XML image to display in my HTML file.  I need to create a tag called "image" in my xml and tag should show an image path that will display an image in my html page.  I have multiple image but one per question.  My XML is below.

```
<questionText>
    <question>Question</question>
        <image>images/image_path1.png</image>
        <answers>
            <choice correct="0">answer1</choice>
            <choice correct="0">answer2</choice>
            <choice correct="1">answer3</choice>
            <choice correct="0">answer4</choice>
    </answers>
</questionText>
<questionText>
    <question>Question</question>
        <image>images/image_path2.png</image>
        <answers>
            <choice correct="0">answer1</choice>
            <choice correct="1">answer2</choice>
            <choice correct="0">answer3</choice>
            <choice correct="0">answer4</choice>
    </answers>
</questionText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DomParser` in JavaScript to parse the XML and then use `document.createElement` to create images dynamically.

```js
var xml = `
<questions>
<questionText>
    <question>Question</question>
        <image>images/image_path1.png</image>
        <answers>
            <choice correct="0">answer1</choice>
            <choice correct="0">answer2</choice>
            <choice correct="1">answer3</choice>
            <choice correct="0">answer4</choice>
    </answers>
</questionText>
<questionText>
    <question>Question</question>
        <image>images/image_path2.png</image>
        <answers>
            <choice correct="0">answer1</choice>
            <choice correct="1">answer2</choice>
            <choice correct="0">answer3</choice>
            <choice correct="0">answer4</choice>
    </answers>
</questionText></questions>`;

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

const images =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image");

for (let image in images){
  if (images[image].tagName == "image"){
    let imagePath = images[image].innerHTML;
    createImage(imagePath);
  }
}


function createImage(path){
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = path;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

References: [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)

Comment: Is there a way to do it just for the image tag and not the rest of the xml code?

Comment: The code I posted only checks the image tag in the XML code. You can remove other child elements and check